# Connecting with R to elasticsearch https with certificate

Tags: r, elasticsearch, httr

I am trying to connect with R to an elasticsearch https instance which requires a certificate.

If I use curl to test if the certificate is correct, it works:

```
curl  'https://username:password@10.x.x.x:9200/_cat/health?v' --cacert /home/username/ca.crt
```

But if I try from R using elastic pkg and httr I get the error:

> ```
> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
>   Server returned nothing (no headers, no data)
> ```

Here is the R code:

```
library(elastic)
library(httr)

set_config(config(cainfo = "/home/username/ca.crt"))

connect(es_host = "10.x.x.x", es_port = 9200, es_user = "username", es_pwd = "password")

elastic::count(index = "indexname-*", type = "datatype")

ml_get <- Search(index = "indexname-*", size = 1, raw = TRUE)
```

I tried using `https://ip_address` but am still getting the same results.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong and your advise.

Comment: `elastic` maintainer here: i haven't dealt with this use case yet, but we can try to make it work. surprised it doesn't work.  can you show me or email me what you get when you do a request for data with `config = verbose()` with `Search()` or `callopts = verbose()` with `count()` - another thing to try is if it works with plain `httr`, e.g , `GET("https://username:password@10.x.x.x:9200/_cat/health?v", config(cainfo = "/home/username/ca.crt"))`

Comment: @sckott, using: GET("username:password@10.x.x.x:9200/_cat/health?v"; , returns the elasticsearch health status which is what we'd expect. When I included the other suggested setting I get back: -> GET /_cat/health?v HTTP/1.1 -> Host: 10.x.x.x:9200 -> Authorization: Basic cnVzZXI6aW43aW9zMWZyXFT8 -> User-Agent: libcurl/7.47.0 r-curl/2.6 httr/1.2.1 -> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate -> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, / -> <- HTTP/1.1 200 OK <- content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 <- content-length: 294 <- Thank you

Comment: @sckott, using elastic::count(), or just Search(), returns the previously reported error: Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Server returned nothing (no headers, no data)

Comment: @sckott, found this error en elasticsearch log file when I run elastic::count() or Search(): [WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [8GMXbRw] caught exception while handling client http         traffic, closing connection [id: 0x2b4b56cd, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9200 ! R:/10.x.x.x:51144]
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 474....0a0d0a

Comment: @sckott .... 
Caused by: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 474...0a0d0a
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1097) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428) ~[?:?]

Comment: @sckott it may very possibly be an issue with the configuration of the elasticsearch although I am not sure. Just found this thread : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/io-netty-handler-ssl-notsslrecordexception-not-an-ssl-tls-record-after-ssl-enabling-my-cluster/77987/10

Comment: can you open an issue here https://github.com/ropensci/elastic/issues

Comment: @sckott I will after I make sure it is not the elasticsearch certification causing this whole issue. Thank you Scott!

Comment: @Vanko did you ever resolve this? I am attempting to do the same things and running into issues as well.